# Creating a preseed.cfg with docker and gitlab-ci-multi-runner installed, why it's always commented out?

Tags: debian, apt, preseed

I have my preseed almost working like I would like but for some reason, I can't have those two repositories added to the source.list file. It's always commented out that it can't verify them.

I know I could put them in a late_command script, but I would really like having them in the cfg file.

```
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string http.us.debian.org
d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian
d-i mirror/http/proxy string http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx

## Setup GITLAB-MULTI-CI-RUNNER
d-i apt-setup/local0/repository string deb https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/debian/ stretch main
d-i apt-setup/local0/source boolean true
d-i apt-setup/local0/key string https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-runner/gpgkey

## Setup DOCKER
d-i apt-setup/local1/repository string deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
d-i apt-setup/local1/source boolean false
d-i apt-setup/local1/key string https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg

d-i debian-installer/allow_unauthenticated boolean true
```

Is there some `d-i` line that I'm missing or it's just plain impossible that way?

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @cgmckeever 4 years later and its still depressing that Debian simply don't care about the fact https is everywhere in the 21st century.  It can be done but you have to do it in a very messy hacky way in `preseed/late_command`

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have run into the exact same issue, at least with the docker repository. I think it has something to do with the fact that it uses **https** instead of **http** as transport. The preseed installer fails to verify the repository because either `apt-transport-https` or `ca-certificates` (or both) are not installed by default, and thus it comments out those lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

In my case I managed to solve the issue by installing the necessary packages and then using a `late_command` to enable the repo post-install.

```
d-i pkgsel/include string ca-certificates apt-transport-https
```

and

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target sed -i 's/^#deb https:/deb https:/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I do agree with you that this is something of a hack, but it's the best I could come up with.

Comment: If you are uncommenting the docker repository with the late command, do you then have to do some magic to install docker? Or are you just manually doing post install now that its available via apt?